# How to use Webelement List in Selenium webdriver for the given scenario?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My query is DESCRIBED below:

I have an excel sheet named hoteldata.xls from where I am importing data and then entering it into the hotel form in the destination textbox. The limitation however is that sendkeys method when sends "comma" as a separator, then the entry from the auto dropdown does not get selected at all.

The situation can be elaborated as below:

Like I have to select "Goa,India" from the dropdown when "Goa" is provided as data from external excel sheet. then in that case my code looks like below snippet:

// Get all items in autocomplete list
                     List items1 = d1.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/ul/li[2]/a"));
                     d1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // Look for item 
                       for( i= 0; i

```
                    if(items1.get(i).getText().contains(s2.getCell(0, k).getContents()))
                    {

                        System.out.println(items1.get(i).getText());

                        items1.get(i).click();
                    break; 
                    }
                    }
```

However, if Like I have to select "New Delhi,India" from the dropdown when "New Delhi" is provided as data from external excel sheet. then in that case my code looks like below snippet:

// Get all items in autocomplete list
                     List items1 = d1.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/ul/li[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvKEO.jpg)/a"));
                     d1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // Look for item 
                       for( i= 0; i

```
                    if(items1.get(i).getText().contains(s2.getCell(0, k).getContents()))
                    {

                        System.out.println(items1.get(i).getText());

                        items1.get(i).click();
                    break; 
                    }
                    }
```

In the above two snippets, we can see that xpath variable value "html/body/ul/li[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvKEO.jpg)/a"))
keeps changing from city to city as per the text which is provided by the external sheet hoteldata.xls

I am figuring out a way so that when any city name is entered in the destination field, then the list of cities/locations which get auto-populated in the dropdown should get stored in the webelement list type variable and then the string matching should be implemented to match the dropdown list elements with the text which is being fetched or imported from the external hoteldata.xls sheet.

Kindly suggest some way to achieve this.[image]

Comment: thankyou fro reviewing but I dont have sufficient reputation points to apply the edits. pls suggest some solution. thanks!

Comment: What does the html code look like for the select?  Is it a Select element?  That image in the question is too small to read anything of value.